# Get ID for each single v.to.points point in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, splitting, grass-7.0, grass-7.1

How do I get for each [**`v.to.points`**](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.to.points.html) point an ID in the database (DB).

So far I splited the line (each 10m) but it returns only **one** DB entry for each original line.

```py
v.db.select line
cat|Id|Name
1|1|Line 1
2|2|Line 2

# split the lines every 10m
v.to.points in=line out=line_points dmax=10

# check the result
v.db.select line_points
cat|Id|Name
1|1|Line 1
2|2|Line 2
```

Each point should have its **own** DB entry. The result should be:

```py
v.db.select line_points
cat|Id|Name
1|1|Line 1
2|1|Line 1
3|2|Line 2
4|2|Line 2
```

---

**Workaround:** So far my workaround is, to export (`v.out.ogr`) the points as shape and import (`v.in.ogr`) it again. Then each point has his own ID. *But there must be a smarter way to do that!*

Comment: Not much of a GRASS user but what about [v.category.add](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.category.html) which is described as: _"...attaches, deletes or reports vector categories to map geometry. These categories (IDs) are used to link geometry object(s) to attribute records (from attribute table linked to vector map)."_

Comment: I tried that before in GRASS 7 the function calls [**`v.category`**](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/v.category.html). What I tried is the following command `v.category in=line_points option=add out=line_points2`. I posted the question 'cuz I have it already for quite a while and work since ever with my workaround, but I felt alway its not the best method to do it.

Comment: Have you looked at https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.segment.html? It looks like it performs a similar function and might work better for creating separate segments rather than vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`v.to.points`**](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.to.points.html) creates a vector with **2 layers**. With the second layer you should have unique ID.

You should thus simply specify the second layer with  [**`v.db.select`**](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.db.select.html) or write into a new feature with [**`v.category`**](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.category.html).

```bash
# return unique IDs
v.db.select line_points layer=2

# change layer 2 to 1
v.category input=line_points output=line_points2 option=chlayer layer=2,1
```

For more details see **`v.to.points`** description:

> `v.to.points` creates points along input lines. The output is a vector
>   with 2 layers. Layer 1 holds the category and attributes of the input
>   lines; all points created along the same line have the same category,
>   equal to the category of that line. **In layer 2 each point has it's**
>   **unique category**; other attributes stored in layer 2 are lcat - the
>   category of the input line and along - the distance from line's start.

Comment: One more time I should have read the manual more carefully. Thx @radouxju that's where I was looking for.