# Attribute table update after v.split on GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, fields-attributes, database

So I just used v.split to create shorter segments (with just 2 vertices) of my contour lines. I was left with about 22000 lines but, when I open the attributes table, I find no more than 45 entry lines.

How can I make it so I have a unique ID for each of my new line segments?

Comment: I think your question sounds similar to this one: [Get ID for each single v.split point in GRASS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169975/get-id-for-each-single-v-split-point-in-grass)

Comment: Spot on! Can't believe I missed that…  anyways I was trying to solve the issue myself, I will gladly join the other topic.  Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Most welcome buddy, hope there's an easy solution to this problem :)